# What's the naming convention for non-async asynchronous method?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

As is known to all, in C#, `async` methods are supposed to be named with suffix "Async" (e.g. `ReadAsync`, `CreateAsync`).

But in many cases, `async/await` is not necessary in an asynchronous method, for instance:

```
public async Task<string> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    return await GetAsync();
}
```

can be rewritten as:

```
public Task<string> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    return GetAsync();
}
```

My question is:

1. For the situation above where `async/await` is totally optional, which version is the more correct? Keep the `async/await` or return a `Task` directly?
2. If the second version is better (returning a `Task` directly), should it conventionally still be named with suffix "Async" (i.e. `DoSomethingAsync`) or not (i.e. `DoSomething`)?

Comment: The two versions are almost identical. (There are some differences in the continuation context, but that is probably not relevant.) The convention is to use the `Async` suffix if you return a task. Doesn't matter whether the task was explicitly created or autogenerated by the compiler. (The caller can't tell the difference.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> For the situation above where async/await is totally optional, which version is the more correct? Keep the async/await or return a Task directly?

I prefer returning a `Task` directly, but I've written [an entire blog post on when this is appropriate and not](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

> If the second version is better (returning a Task directly), should it conventionally still be named with suffix "Async" (i.e. DoSomethingAsync) or not (i.e. DoSomething)?

Yes. The `Async` suffix means "returns an awaitable".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just out of curiosity, will returning a `Task` directly be more efficient or the compiler will optimize out the differences? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I am reading your blog post. It's a good post but I am a little bit confused about the exception part, why would exception be thrown in `var task = GetElidingKeywordsAsync(); `? I thought exception from `Task` would not be thrown until explicitly invoking `Wait()`. Thank you so much!

Comment: @LifuHuang: Because it's the `async` keyword that places the exception on the task. If you elide `async`, then any exceptions thrown are thrown directly and not placed on the task.

Comment: But `public Task<string> GetElidingKeywordsAsync()` also returns a `Task<string>`, right? I think neither should it throw an exception before it being awaited(or calling `Wait()` on it).

Comment: @LifuHuang: Yes, that's the expected semantics. That's why you have to be careful with exceptions when eliding `async`.

Comment: So this line (`var task = GetElidingKeywordsAsync();`) actually will not throw an exception, right?

Comment: @LifuHuang: No. It *will* throw an exception because it does not use `async`.

Comment: `GetElidingKeywordsAsync()` internally calls `GetStringAsync()` without any `Wait()` or `await`. Wouldn't the `Task<string>` returned from `GetStringAsync()` be directly returned by `GetElidingKeywordsAsync()`?

Comment: @LifuHuang: The example we're talking about calls `DownloadStringAsync`, not `GetStringAsync`. And it will not even call `DownloadStringAsync` if `/* Something that can throw an exception */` throws an exception.